# How to use the output of cv2.HoughLinesP() to rotate the original image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm using `cv2.HoughLinesP()` and it's giving me lines it has detected. These lines are mostly accurate at finding the angle of the object. Then, I want to rotate the original image according to these lines.

**My image:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread(img)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=10)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),5)
cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**The result:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Comment: From the line end points, compute the angle of the lines and the length. Assuming you want landscape mode, find the longer two lines. Then average their angles. Then use the angle to rotate the line. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707673/find-angle-in-degrees-from-one-point-to-another-in-2d-space

Comment: But why not just get the contour and then rotated bounding box which returns the angle. See cv2.findContours() and cv2.minAreaRect().

Comment: See also https://inneka.com/ml/opencv/how-to-straighten-a-rotated-rectangle-area-of-an-image-using-opencv-in-python-2/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to perform skew correction. Instead of using [`cv2.HoughLinesP`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html#probabilistic-hough-transform) to find the angle and rotate the object, you can use [`cv2.minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) to find the angle then [`cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrotationmatrix2d) + [`cv2.warpAffine`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine) to deskew the image.

Input `->` Output

[image]
[image]

Skew angle

```
-29.35775375366211
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold 
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Compute rotated bounding box
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle
print(angle)

# Rotate image to deskew
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** For other skew correction techniques take a look at

1. [Python OpenCV skew correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964634/python-opencv-skew-correction-for-ocr/57965160)
2. [How to de-skew an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660933/how-to-de-skew-a-text-image-also-retrieve-the-new-bounding-box-of-that-image/59672620)
3. [Detect image orientation angle based on text direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010660/detect-image-orientation-angle-based-on-text-direction/58020893)

Comment: While this is an excellent answer in most cases, the reason why I am using `HoughLines()` is because what you suggested never worked for me. In contrast, `HoughLines()` always gets the correct lines.

Comment: Instead of using `HoughlinesP` to obtain the angle, I recommend trying to find the angle of the entire object

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?